# Sharepoint 2010. Strange behavior in intranet: ip address vs dns name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have Sharepoint site published in Intranet. Most of the time I configure modules and site collection via http://myserver link. But some users have to use ip address: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Users that access site via ip address observe strange behavior - children sites menus work inappropriate and some services looks misconfigured.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the "myserver" DNS name configured ? Did you have an entry in the company DNS added or did you modify some host files ? In the second case, this explains the problem. You can either modify all host files (not recommended at all) or add a real DNS entry to the DNS server.

The strange behavior is typical of Alternate Access Mapping problems, but I advise to solve the first problem and the second will disappear.

Comment: would you mind elaborating a bit further on this? It seemed intuitive to me to alter the hosts file of the server my intranet site lives on, but having the company's IT dept add the DNS entry to the DNS server is what ended up fixing the issue. Also, what does it mean to "add the DNS entry to the company's DNS server?" This may help me communicate needs with IT in the future. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use the hosts file, all the computers accessing the server need to have their hosts file modified. Depending on the size of your IT infrastructure, this can be a lot of work. A DNS server has a list of mappings from computer names to iP addresses. Adding a new entry means adding such a mapping.

Comment: thank you. What happens when a new computername is added to the network? Does IT have to go back and edit this list? Or is "it" as simple as checking "apply to all servers on network" using the network management tools available to them?

Comment: If your network uses a DNS server, all computers in the network know about all DNS entries. If you use hosts file, you need to edit each one, and yes also the file of a new computer.

Comment: got it. Thank you again.